# Problema para acceder al servidor Apache desde una red local, con nombre de dominio y SSL

Tags: linux, webservice, ubuntu, apache2

Tengo configurado un servidor Apache en Ubuntu 16 en una máquina con una ip fija 192.168.1.130 .En la configuración predeterminada, es posible acceder a este servidor desde otras máquinas (de la misma red) sin problemas. Como estoy trabajando con sockets, incluí certificados de seguridad SSL quedando el archivo /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl.conf configurado de esta manera:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.130:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName  misitiolocal.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/misitiolocal.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/misitiolocal.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/misitiolocal.ca-bundle.crt

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>


    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Luego configuré el archivo /etc/host de esta manera:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost         <- así estaba
127.0.1.1       NombreDeLaMaquina <- así estaba
192.168.1.130   misitiolocal.com  <- lo agregue yo
```

Luego de habilitar el modo SSL en Apache con la nueva configuración y reiniciar el servidor, al ingresar desde el mismo servidor no hay problema. Funciona y me resuelve bien por ip y por nombre: `https://misitiolocal.com` y se despliega el servicio correctamente.

Pero al ingresar desde otra máquina ( misma red local)  me arroja el error "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" lo que me dice que hay un error en la resolución del DNS. De hecho, cuando ingreso desde con la IP 192.168.1.130 me lo cambia a el nombre del dominio `https://misitio.com`, pero me aparece el mismo error ( es decir ve la ip, trata de resolver el nombre, pero no puede). Como antecedente tengo ping a 192.168.1.130 desde otras máquinas, pero no tengo ping a misitiolocal.com

-La carpeta /var/www tiene los permisos correspondientes para www-data 
-No deseo configurar el archivo host de las maquinas clientes (que estén en windows) por que debería resolver incluso si llega una máquina nueva.

**Preguntas abiertas:**

- Puede que sea tema de configuración router?
- Puede que me falte otra configuración en Apache?
- o definitivamente hay que montar un servidor DNS en la máquina servidor?

Se agradecen consejos y ayudas

Comment: Por tu explicacion el unico que conoce esta direccion dns es tu servidor ya que lo configurastes directamente en el /etc/hosts, al ingresar a la ip se te direcciona al sitio seguro de https://tusitio.com que ninguna maquina en la red conoce y lo que hace es ir donde el provedor dns configurado y este le dice que tampoco lo conoce.. la solucion seria configurar ese dns directamente en to router o firewall o especificarselo a tu maquina directamente en el /etc/hosts/ o en C:\windows\system32\drives\etc\hosts o implementar un dns server

Comment: Gracias @bryo siguiendo tu consejo, en estos momentos estoy lidiando con bind9 pero todos los tutoriales de la red dicen cosas distintas y aun estoy en eso...

Comment: Hola, ya resolviste el problema? yo sigo atorado en algo similar. Tengo corriendo MAMP con virtual hosts y SSL (con mkcert) funcionando perfectamente en un mini mac, y estoy tratando de acceder desde un macbook pro en el que también he instalado MAMP. Añadí los nombres de dominio al archivo hosts del macbook apuntando a la IP del mini mac y logro acceder a los sitios del localhost  del mini mac, pero cuando trato de acceder con https me tira la advertencia de certificado inválido. Trate de añadir ese certificado al llavero, pero no tuve éxito y sigue sin validar el SSL... pfff